# как в vscode редактировать выпадающее меню подсказок (картинка внутри) или как добавить свои сниппеты

Tags: visual-studio-code

Как поменять местами выпадающее меню 1-е(создает только слово) со 2-м (создает function name(){}). Или как удалить 1 значение

[image: function]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать следующую настройку в файле `settings.json`

```
  "editor.suggestSelection": "recentlyUsedByPrefix"
```

Это не поменяет порядок следования элементов в suggestions, но сделает активным последний используемый.

Внести изменения можно следующим образом:

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
2. В поле поиска ввести наименование настройки `editor.suggestSelection`
3. Изменить значение на `recentlyUsedByPrefix`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   [Создать свой собственный сниппет.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_creating-your-own-snippets)

Comment: Спасибо попробую

Answer (score 2):

Это меню вы никак не измените, оно формируется динамически, исходя из того, что вы пытаетесь написать и предлагает возможные варианты.

Comment: Уверен, это самое «динамически» можно настроить в каких-то пределах

Comment: я пишу расширение и там создаю как-раз такое "меню". Настроить его не представляется возможным. Возможно настройка реализована в поддержке других языков, но я об этом не знаю. Единственное - в настройках ввести editor.Suggest - выдаст соответствующие настройки. Но изменить там содержимое выпадающего меню нельзя.